# How to delete all the options in an option group

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I have created a few options with with the `register_setting` function:

```
<?php register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback ); ?>
```

Is there a way to clear the whole content of the `$option_group`, and even the group itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the Codex is a good resource for doing research on things like this ... and there are functions related to `register_setting()` listed directly on [it's page in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting#Related).

The function you're looking for is `unregister_setting()`.  From [it's Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_setting):

> ### Description
>
> Allows clean de-registration of registered settings. Should be used mostly in deactivation hooks.
>
> ### Usage
>
> `unregister_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback );`

Comment: Yea I have seen this, but you still have to specify an `$option_name`. Is there no way to access the content of the option group itself. I think I have created some options from which I do not know the names anymore. That's why I want to remove the whole option group. I know about the Codex and the unregister function, should have added that to the question. I am looking for a better solution, if there is any.

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is delete some of those old options from your database, correct?

Comment: Yes I want to delete the options that were created in the option group. I do not know them all by name, but they were stored in one group. They don't bother me, but there has to be a way to get rid of them and keep things clean.

Comment: Well I will just accept this as an answer. I still can not find anything that will completely solve this issue, but this is as close as you can get.

Comment: From what I read (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026219/where-wordpress-store-option-group-information) option groups aren't stored, only defined in code. So I guess you'll have to unregister them indeed.